# What does Charting`$MajorTickLength do?

Tags: plotting, undocumented, scidraw

I know I can specify tick lengths using the `Ticks` option in `Plot` and related functions, and I also know about the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/CustomTicksGuide.pdf) package. But I stumbled over the symbols

```
Charting`$MajorTickLength
(* 4 *)
```

and

```
Charting`$MinorTickLength 
(* 2.5 *)
```

and am curious if I could just set these to globally change tick sizes, without ever specifying the `Ticks` option in plots. Changing these values, however, does not seem to have any effect. Does anyone know what these constants are there for?

Comment: You can set defaults for CustomTicks using `SetOptions[LinTicks,MajorTickLength -> {0.04, 0}]` or similar. However, you still need to tell `Plot` to actually use `LinTicks`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just curious about these constants.

Comment: ``Charting`$MajorTickLength`` is builtin private symbol, it is not related to the CustomTicks package. I doubt that it is possible to set the default tick lengths by setting such a constant because I believe ticks are handled by the front end. My understanding is that if the ticks are set to `Automatic`, they will be fully generated by the front end, while the symbol you are referring to lives in the kernel. These are of course just some educated guesses. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place I've found an effect is

```
Block[{Charting`$MajorTickLength = 15},
 CandlestickChart[{"C", {{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 1, 15}}}, 
  TrendStyle -> {Green, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare with the default:

```
CandlestickChart[{"C", {{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 1, 15}}}, 
 TrendStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are probably other functions like `CandlestickChart`, which calls `` Charting`CategoricalAxis[] ``, which uses `` Charting`$MajorTickLength ``.

Simon Woods found a user-level function that is affected by both `` Charting`$MajorTickLength `` and `` Charting`$MinorTickLength ``, namely `PairedBarChart`.

If it's any help, several internal functions (inspect `` ? Charting`*Scale `` functions) that use the following, which uses the minor tick length:

```
Charting`AxisDump`iQuantitativeScale[]
```

Comment: `PairedBarChart` is affected by both the major and minor setting.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks. I figured there would be some other `*Chart` functions, but my enthusiasm for tracking them all down was waning.

Comment: @SimonWoods For me, `PairedBarChart` does not respond to changing ``Charting`$MajorTickLenth``.  The major ticks always seem cut off by numbers. Do you have an example?

Comment: e.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egcqX.png)

Comment: @SimonWoods OK, maybe I had a typo in `$MajorTickLength` -- it's all working now. Thanks again and sorry for the trouble.